# Eigen - add method for writing to two matrices simultaneously

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have a matrix of structs, where each struct contains two values. I'm trying to extend Eigen in some way that will allow me to read the matrix of structs to two matrices of values without having to iterate through the matrix of structs twice (i.e., once for each value):

```
template <typename T>
struct dummy_str{
    T a_;
    T b_;
};

int main()
{
    dummy_str<double> d1;
    d1.a_ = 0;
    d1.b_ = 1;

    Eigen::Matrix<dummy_str<double>, -1, -1> d_mat(2, 2);
    d_mat << d1, d1, d1, d1;

    Eigen::MatrixXd a_out(2,2);
    Eigen::MatrixXd b_out(2,2);

    //Trying to implement something like this:
    //d_mat.read_struct(a_out, b_out);

}
```

Which of Eigen's customisation methods (if any) would let me implement this? The closest I've come is adding a CwiseUnaryOp for reading each value in a void expression using the MatrixBase addons, but that would still traverse the matrix twice:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
void read_struct(OtherDerived& other1, OtherDerived& other2) {
    other1.derived() = derived().read_a();
    other2.derived() = derived().read_b();
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution to be found here?

EDIT: I managed to achieve what I want with a NullaryExpr, but this only works with non-const inputs.

```
template <typename OtherDerived>
auto read_struct(OtherDerived& other1, OtherDerived& other2) {
  return Derived::NullaryExpr(derived().rows(), derived().cols(),
                              [&] (Index i, Index j){
                                other1.derived().coeffRef(i,j) = derived().coeff(i,j).a_;
                                other2.derived().coeffRef(i,j) = derived().coeff(i,j).b_;
                              });
}
```

If I attempt to use the above expr with a const input matrix (`d_mat` in the first example), with an error about 'discarding qualifiers.

Comment: Related: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/issues/984

Comment: Thanks for the reference @chtz , would you mind looking at the code I posted in the edit above and letting me know if there's a way to extend this to const inputs?

Comment: Did you try `auto read_struct(OtherDerived& other1, OtherDerived& other2) const {...}` ?

Comment: That did the trick. it's now implemented, but it looks like no copying happens when the expression is called. I've got an example [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uDVhY5), have I missed something?

Comment: @chtz Forgot to tag you in the previous comment. I implemented a nullary functor for copying values to two matrices simultaneously, but no copying happens when I call it. The example is [on godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/dKG3pb), would you mind taking a look when you have a minute?